# codeigniter installation problem on shared host

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, codeigniter, shared-hosting

my host account is something like:

~
~/public_html
~/public_html/system/application

to access my web, I need to put http://example.com/~userid in address bar

I install codeigniter in the ~/public_html directory, I can access http://example.com/~userid.

The Welcome page shows correctly, and the related user guide pages show correctly.

The problem is: if I create a new controller, and create new views, the web page just show "Error 404: Document Not Found". If I use http://example.com/~userid/welcome/index it has the same problem.

If I use base_url() function it shows http://example.com/~userid/

What should I do do fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try http://example.com/~userid/index.php/welcome/index.

It looks like your URL rewriting is not set up or badly configured. This is the default way if URL rewriting is disabled.

**EDIT** See [this page of the user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html), especially the section "Removing the index.php file" on how to set up URL rewriting.

Comment: I would follow @Franz's suggestion and look into your URL rewriting in the **.htaccess** file.

Comment: Then you can accept this answer. Gives you 2 reputation points and me, uhm, a little more ;)